# How to perform mysqldump in PHP without using exec()?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run this code:

```
$cmd = '/usr/bin/mysqldump --user=myUsername --password="myPassword" --host=localhost myDatabase > myOutputSqlFilePath;
exec($cmd, $output, $return_val);
```

But it fails, as it seems `exec()` is not available for PHP on this particular server. (I have confirmed this by trying to run `exec("mkdir test-dir", $output, $return_val);` which fails to create the test directory.)

So, I would like to know what other options I have to perform the mysqldump in PHP?

Now, I have some related PHP code that creates a database, like this:

```
function createDb($cPanelUser, $cPanelPass, $dbName) {

    $buildRequest = "/frontend/paper_lantern/sql/addb.html?db=$dbName";

    $openSocket = fsockopen('localhost',2082);
    if(!$openSocket) {
        return "Socket error";
        exit();
    }

    $authString = $cPanelUser . ":" . $cPanelPass;
    $authPass = base64_encode($authString);
    $buildHeaders  = "GET " . $buildRequest ."\r\n";
    $buildHeaders .= "HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $buildHeaders .= "Host:localhost\r\n";
    $buildHeaders .= "Authorization: Basic " . $authPass . "\r\n";
    $buildHeaders .= "\r\n";

    fputs($openSocket, $buildHeaders);
    while(!feof($openSocket)) {
        fgets($openSocket,128);
    }
    fclose($openSocket);
}
```

So maybe there is something like this that can be used to perform the mysqldump?

Or maybe there's an entirely different solution??

Comment: Are you sure `exec` is not available?  Did you try `function_exists( 'exec' );`?  I would try running the `$cmd` from the command line as yourself to make sure it works.  When I run into issues w/exec it's usually a permissions issue.  When you ran your `mkdir` test, were you creating the directly in a location where permissions allows it?

Comment: That's a much better test, thank you - but it has confirmed that `exec()` does not exist. I don't think I have a command line facility either. Is it normally within cPanel?

Comment: This sounds like you need to work with your hosting provider to get this feature, since they would probably object if you found a workaround.
You could try seeing if the [process control extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php) is enabled. If you're on a Windows server, there's a comment at the bottom of that page I linked to showing use of `COM()` to invoke programs. You should either get permission from your hosting provider, or ask if they have a recommended workaround. Ultimately, you may have to change to a different provider.

Comment: Use `phpinfo()` to know which php functions are disabled in your server (look for `disable_functions`).  Maybe they are blocking some but not all of them, for instance, `shell_exec`

Comment: Cheers for the help guys, but I got the requirement sorted the end using PHP's mysqli as a workaround to exec() not being available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exec()` wasn't available, so in the end I solved this by using **mysqli** with SHOW CREATE tables and then selecting all the rows, and creating/populating the new database with that data - all with **mysqli**.